# how to get progress circle before loading fragment on click of item in the navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer in my app.On the click of an item from the navigation drawer particular fragment gets loaded.
but loading of a fragment is taking time of few seconds. i want a progress spinner to display in between so that it does not look like it got stuck.
i tried for using asynchronous task but it did not work because loading fragment from  drawer does not include any background process.
Please suggest me something.

**Navigation Drawer Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_navigation_fragments);




    toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.test_nav_tool);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    SharedPreferences w = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor share = w.edit();
    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);

  ////if user skip-logout button in nav drawer will disable.
    loggedIn=(w.getBoolean("loggedIn", loggedIn));
    if(loggedIn==false){
        nvDrawer.getMenu().findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(false);
    }



    String user_name = (w.getString("name", user));
    String type = "b";
    type=(w.getString("type", type));
    if(user_name.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
        user_name="Guest User";


    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("b")){
        nvDrawer.getMenu().findItem(R.id.add_kitchen).setVisible(false);
        nvDrawer.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_slideshow).setVisible(false);

    }
     header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.test_header_xml, null);
     nvDrawer.addHeaderView(header);
    TextView tv1=(TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.upload_image);


    tv1.setText(user_name);

    setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
    drawerToggle=setupDrawerToggle();
    mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        nvDrawer.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(R.id.nav_camera, 0);
    }

}
private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
    return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(TestNavigationFragments.this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);



}



@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}


@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    drawerToggle.syncState();

}


private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);

                    return true;
                }
            });
}


public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());

    switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_camera:



            fragment=new TESTfragNEIBMAP();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_share:
            fragment =  new  TestFragACCOUNT();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_send:
            fragment = new TESTfragSUPPORT();
            break;
        case R.id.add_kitchen:
            fragment = new TestfragSELLER();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_slideshow:
            fragment=new TestAddKitchenHistory();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_gallery:
            fragment=new TestNavOrder();
            break;
        case R.id.logout:
            try {
                SharedPreferences s = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = s.edit();
                editor.clear().commit();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;
            }catch (Exception e){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        case R.id.nav_track:
            fragment = new  TestTrack();
            break;
    }


    if(fragment!=null){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();


    }

    // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    // Set action bar title
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    // Close the navigation drawer
    mDrawer.closeDrawers();
}
```

}

**UPDATE**
I have also tried writing progess code in drawer activity and dismiss it in Fragment onViewCreated() method...but i did not see any progress spinner  at the time when i click on item of drawer because map is opened and it called its onViewCreated method very fast.

the other option can be adding splash screen on click of item in drawer till map will load but i don't have idea how to do it like how to finish splash screen when the map will become properly visible.

Comment: Show  a progressbar inside your fragment and dismiss once that fragment loaded completely

Comment: You should probably show the relevant bits of your code to make the issue reproducible and for others to be able to help you.

Comment: i have updated my ques..please help me in resolving the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the issue resolved by closing the drawer before loading the fragments using handler class and set the progress dialog code in onClick of navigation drawer item.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog progress; // Global varibale

// Initiate it in `OnCreateView()`
progress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "dialog title",
    "dialog message", true);

//When Loaded data
progress.dismiss();
```

Comment: @chandra change `this` to `getActivity()`. if still have issues comment here.

Comment: i want to do this for loading map. so i should write this progress.dismiss() in onViewCreated() method?

Comment: @chandra unless you show your code i can suggest anything.

Comment: please see my updated code...if i write the progress spinner code  in the fragment that i will not resolve my issue because it will show the progress bar after map fragment will load and I WANT the progress bar to be shown before loading the map fragment(after i click the item in the navigation drawer) i want the same procedure for all the other fragment...i have tried in the navigation drawer onclick of item and it was showing the progress bar..but i am not able to find where to dismiss it.thanks